# Android Service Won't Start

Tags: android, service

Strange problem I'm facing. I want to start a Service when my Activity is created. Here is my Service's code (very simple, as you'll see):

```
package com.nblmedia.service;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class ServiceSynchro extends Service {

public ServiceSynchro()
{
    Log.i(XXX.LOG, "ServiceSynchro");
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    Log.i(XXX.LOG, "onBind");
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i(XXX.LOG, "onCreate");
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.i(XXX.LOG, "onDestroy");
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

In my AndroidManifest.xml I have declared the Service as follow :

```
<service android:name=".ServiceSynchro"></service>
```

Finaly, to start my Service, I call the startService method in the onCreate :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    startService(new Intent(UserMenuActivity.this, ServiceSynchro.class));      
}
```

And nothing happens. If I check the device's running services, there are no service named ServiceSyncho running. If I check the Logcat, nothing is outputted. Same for the breakpoints, the app doesn't cycle thru the Service's lifecycle events. Any idea what could be my problem?

Comment: You could try implementing Service.onStartCommand(..) to see if it gets called at least.

Answer (score 10):

I found the problem. In my AndroidManifest.xml file, the service:name attribute wasn't refering to the fully qualified classname of the service. As example, I was using this :

```
<service android:name=".ServiceSynchro"></service>
```

When I needed :

```
<service android:name="com.xxx.service.ServiceSynchro"></service>
```

For the people interested in the application from the documentation, [here is the link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html#nm) to view it.

> **android:name**
>   The name of the Service subclass that implements the service. This should be a fully   qualified class name (such as, "com.example.project.RoomService"). However, as a shorthand, if the first character of the name is a period (for example, ".RoomService"), it is appended to the package name specified in the  element.

Lastly, I updated the code to override the onStartCommand command since the onStart method is deprecated.

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
```

Answer (score 4):

Get rid of your constructor. Never implement a constructor in a component (sole current exception: `IntentService`).

Also, when you do implement constructors elsewhere in Java, chain to the superclass.

Answer (score 0):

I looked everywhere when my service didnt start.
Nothing worked out.Finally debugging of the third hour ı found out that my package name was not the standart format xx.xx.xx package names.I fixed and it worked.
For your information.